# Custom module doesn't show up in the list of apps

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to install module from odoo 8 to odoo 9.

I just copied over the whole folder to the `addons` folder in odoo 9 and was expecting that I can somehow *install* the module in odoo 9 but it doesn't show up in the list of apps to install. Is there anything changed in the structure of odoo that I have to prepare the module to show up in the apps list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello freddy, there are lots of change from V8 to V9 specifically change of API so which module you are trying to install custom.? some addons work perfect in v9 also.

Comment: Hey @Bazzinga... I created my own module just for one company and they now want to upgrade. Do you think it is a good strategy to create a new module from a scaffold and then step by step adapt the old code to the new api?

Comment: Not at all, You should migrate that module. For more info to migrate visit here https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/guidelines.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not see your modules/apps because you must update list of modules.

First what you need is **restart server**.

After this login with Administrator and activate **Developer mode**.

Go to Settings(top menu) -> Update Apps List(left menu) -> refresh page(or better: logout, clear cache, restart server etc. :) ).

After this steps you must see your modules.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for my reputation... Dear users, I'm not saying that the module from v8 will work on v9. I just guess why the modules/apps is invisible in settings.

Comment: That did the trick. Now the update module list is hidden in the developer mode which has changed since 8.0.

Comment: In odoo 9 - developer mode can be found by going to Administrator>About>(window pops up with button 'Activate Developer Mode').

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to add my 2 cents.

I'm new to Odoo and it's interface is not familiar to me so I had trouble locating my module even after I entered ***'Developer mode'*** and clicked ***'Update apps list'***.

In ***'Apps'*** menu - under the search field there is ***'Filters'*** button, and to show custom modules ***'Extra'*** option must be selected.

You can also delete all the filters directly from the search bar and just type the name of your new module there.

Comment: Also make sure to restart the server if this doesn't help. Sometimes it caches a lot. See the accepted answer for this.

Comment: Why is this default?! That was so frustrating to figure out. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to remove all filters and search for the custom module by its name. It works +1

Comment: Thank you so much! I had check extra to see the custom module I created. I spent a lot of time figuring out how to do that (I'm using Odoo 10)

Comment: Thanks, Andrew Furletov, it helped me to find my module!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue; after '**Update Apps List**' the 'addon' appeared on the addons list, and I could install it.

But it didn't appear in the Window menu.
So I had to do the following as well (set my User to Admin - or User):
**Manage Users / Your user /** Your addon: **tick** Administrator (Then Refresh)