# Odoo 13.0 Can't see my installed module on the menu

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I am a newbie on Odoo 13.0 (and any Odoo version). I just built my first module, and successfully installed it. The problem is that I can't see my installed module on the menu. I have tried restarting the server and also I have researched these sources but anything seems to work for me:

**Sources**:

1. [Odoo Official Docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/backend.html)
2. [Custom module doesn't show up in the list of apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620237/custom-module-doesnt-show-up-in-the-list-of-apps)
3. [My module is installed but i cannot see it in the menu](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/i-can-t-see-the-menu-item-after-install-a-new-module-161504)

Here are my files, so hopefully, someone could point me out in the right direction.

**__manifest__.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "sample_app",

    'summary': """
        Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
        subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

    'description': """
        Long description of module's purpose
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    # Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
    # Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_module_category_data.xml
    # for the full list
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
    'installable':True,
    'auto_install':False,
    'application':True
}
```

**__init__.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from . import controllers
from . import models
```

**models/models.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class StudentRecord(models.Model):
    _name = "student.student"
    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    middle_name = fields.Char(string="Middle Name", required=True)
    last_name = fields.Char(srtring="Last Name", required=True)
    photo = fields.Binary(string="Photo")
    student_age = fields.Integer(string="Age")
    student_dob = fields.Date(string="Date of Birth")
    student_gender = fields.Selection([("m","Male"),("f","Female"),("o","Other")], string="Gender")
    student_blood_group = fields.Selection(
            [
                ("A+","A+ve"),
                ("B+","B+ve"),
                ("O+","O+ve"),
                ("AB+","AB+ve"),
                ("A-","A-ve"),
                ("B+","B-ve"),
                ("O-","O-ve"),
                ("AB-","AB-ve"),
                ], string = "Blood Group")
```

**views/views.xml**

```py
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>

  <record id="view_student_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">student.student.form</field>
    <field name="model">student.student</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="8" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Student">
            <sheet>
                <field name="photo" widget="image" class="oe_left oe_avatar" />
                <div class="oe_title">
                    <h1>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-right:10px;"><field name="name" required="1" placeholder="First Name" /></td>
                                <td style="padding-right:10px;"><field name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" /></td>
                                <td style="padding-right:10px;"><field name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <notebook colspan="4">
                    <page name="personal_information"
                        string="Personal Information">
                        <group col="4" colspan="4"
                            name="personal_detail">
                            <field name="student_gender" />
                            <field name="student_age" />
                            <field name="student_dob" />
                            <field name="student_gender" />
                            <field name="student_blood_group" />
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
  </record>

  <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_view_students">
    <field name="name">Students</field>
    <field name="res_model">student.student</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">[]</field>
  </record>

  <menuitem id="menu_school" name="School"/>
  <menuitem id="school_student" name="Students" parent="menu_school" action="action_view_students"/>

</odoo>
```

**Edit:**
Here is the image of the menu, I was expecting to see my **sample_test** application in there after installation.

[image: Not in the menu]

Also, Odoo shows my installed app here:

[image: Installed app]

I appreciate your time and help in the matter. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found how to do it. These are the steps I followed to solve my problem:

1. As shown in the image, I don't have the **School** module on my menu.

[image]

2. So, I went to **Settings** and Activated the **Developer Mode** (First one)

[image]

3. Then after the page was reloaded, my **main bar** (not sure about the actual name of it) turned into this:

[image]

4. I noticed that a **bug** appeared in my **main bar**

[image]

5. Then for the sake of curiosity, I clicked on the **bug** and selected the option **Become superuser**

[image] [image]

6. I noticed that my **main bar** changed like this:

[image]

7. Finally, after opening the **Menu** my module was there!! (hooray!)

[image]

And, that is the end for the story (for now) I still need to figure out how to deploy this changes into production, but that my friends is another story!

Thanks!

Comment: The superuser bypass security rules. You need to add [security rules](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/security.html) for your model and specify which groups have access to the menu item (go to Settings/Technical/User Interface/Menu Items then configure groups in Access Rights tab).

Comment: Thanks, @Kenly. So I have to first add the group, I imagine that my application will have two groups: User and Administrator, User will have just Read Rights and Administrator will have read/write rights. Is that correct? So I have also to create two groups in Odoo 13.0 UI Administrator and User.

Comment: Yes. You can also use the existing groups and users. for example `base.user_admin` (admin) is the human admin user, `base.user_root` is the technical admin user and you can add a regular user to `base.group_user` (User types / Internal User).

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I will give it a try and update this answer to see how did it go!

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because of **`security file`**. Because you didn't set security to that model.

Let me explain it with more details: *You're creating your custom model and views with menus and all that stuff but you didn't assign anyone who can **read** these things, who can **write**, who can **delete** and etc that is why you're facing this issue your view is created and your model with your custom fields have been created successfully in back end but not visible*

> For that we will use our security file to grant access to our required
> group/users

**security/ir.model.access.csv**

> id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
> access_student_student,access.student.student,model_student_student,base.group_user,1,1,1,1

Here you can see I'm giving access to **base.group_user** and what of access I'm giving? Here you can see 1s which means YES and I'm giving permission of reading(**prem_read**), permission of write(**prem_write**), permission of create(**prem_create**) and last one permission of deletion(**prem_unlink**).

Permission of read will able you to read(view) your model in graphical form.

**Note: Dont forget to add security file in your manifest file in data list**

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it happens when we haven't added our security file in manifest, I see in the code that its been commented out

Answer (score 0):

Another hint, set your user to the proper group:

**Settings / Manage Users / Your User (Edit) / Other /**
Tick [ ] the proper group - e.g. Your module: Admin